# Known resources about "Pixel queries" in WebGL

Tags: webgl

Are there any WebGL resources about the "Pixel queries" technique that was a chapter in Dave Kircher's presentation "Portal problems"?

https://youtu.be/riijspB9DIQ?t=1518

He was talking about rendering a quad when rendering a light source and then after a couple frames querying the rendering system how many pixels of that quad where actually drawn which determined the bloom intensity and I'm intrested if there are ways of replicating that in WebGL.

Google search gives results like WebGLRenderingContext: readPixels() method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels). Though it seems like you are already supposed to know where the quad was rendered in screen space and implicitly the area of it too.

Comment: What he's talking about is [occlusion queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082085/webgl-2-0-occlusion-query).